# Kafka state store rollback on topology exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-platform

I am trying to use a state store to deduplicate messages received by a kafka-streams topology (i.e. duplicate based upon some business-derived deduplication key in case a producer duplicates messages over some long period of time).

I notice that if I add a value to the keystore during the transform step, and then throw an exception in a subsequent step, the subscription is rolled back to the previous checkpoint, but the state store keeps its values, which seems incorrect.

Is there a 'correct' way of using the state store in a topology such that state is rolled back upon the topology throwing an exception?

n.b. this behaviour is replicated even with Kafka's exactly-once delivery semantics

E.g (simplified).

Toloplogy:

```
streamsBuilder
    .addStateStore(storeBuilder)
    .<String, MessageType>stream("input-topic")
    .transform(() -> new Deduplicator(storeName))
    .map(mapper::explode) //just throws an exception
    .to(output-topic);
```

Dedplication transformer:

```
public KeyValue<String, MessageType> transform(String key, MessageType value) {

    String transactionId = getTransactionId();
    boolean isDuplicate;

    try (WindowStoreIterator<String> timeIterator = deduplicationStore.fetch(transactionId, calculateWindowStart(), calculateWindowEnd())){
        isDuplicate = timeIterator.hasNext();
    }

    if (isDuplicate(transactionId)) {
        return null;
    }

    deduplicationStore.put(transactionId, transactionId, Instant.now().toEpochMilli());

    return KeyValue.pair(key, value);
}
```

Comment: How do you access the store? The store is not attached to the transformer (or is it just a c&p error)? For non-eos the described behavior is expected -- it's at-least-once processing. one thing you could do, is to use `context.forward()` instead of `return` and first forward the data downstream, and update the store afterwards. With EOS enabled, it should work as expected though. If it does not, it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yep - C&P omission when recreating a simplified topology to demonstrate the problem, but the deduplicator gets the state store by calling `context.getStateStore(storeName)`.  I confirm this behaviour can still be replicated using exactly-once semantics.  Not sure the context.forward would work, since its the subsequent processing stage that throws the exception.  Updating the store afterwards also exposes us to duplicates until a message reaches the end of the topology.

Comment: "Updating the store afterwards also exposes us to duplicates until a message reaches the end of the topology" -- that's correct. With at-least-once guarantees, it's hard to get right... Not sure atm, what a good solution would be. For the EOS case, could you open a JIRA?

Comment: Hi @MatthiasJ.Sax I did create a proof-of-concept to show the state-store misbehaving, but it seems to just work.  Do you know if the issue has been fixed since May?
I don't think its appropriate to raise an issue any more haha https://github.com/spadger/kafka-streams-sad-state-store

Comment: I am not aware of any change with this regard -- there are some new bug-fix releases since May -- not sure if you upgraded? The duplicates you saw, might also be subject to "user error" (ie, incorrect test setup). As long as we cannot reproduce, opening a Jira does not help I guess.

Comment: Hi, it turned out I was using a random UUID as the application (hence state-store location) for each execution.  With a fixed application name, I can confirm the problem definitely exists.

Here is the Jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7192

Comment: Thanks! We will look into it!